# Removing all Google data except the Play store

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, google

My main Android device is a phone. I recently acquired a tablet which I don't really use for email, calendars, etc. Therefore I want none of that data on the tablet.

I have disabled sync for all entries under my Google account, but the emails/calendars/hangouts which were already synced remain on the device.

How can I remove my emails/calendar entries/hangouts/etc from the device while keeping the Play store credentials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure for all apps involved, but for most the "general rule of thumbs" applies:

1. go to *Settings→Apps*
2. select the "All" tab (to also show pre-installed apps)
3. walk the apps one-by-one, open their entries, and select "Clear Cache" plus "Delete Data"

Especially exclude things like "Google Play Services", but include the "Calendar Provider" and "Contacts Provider" (or similar named entries).

It's a good idea to first make a [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) (just in case), and also to keep log of what you cleared. The former in case you hit one app too much, the latter in case you need to perform a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) one day – as after that, sync would be automatically enabled by default, and you can only disable it after having finished the wizard and re-created your account – so all calendars, contacts, etc. would be back.

Comment: That worked just fine, thank you! Now there is no more data on my device.

Answer (score 5):

*As always, do a backup of your device before removing anything.*

*If you don't understand something that is stated, please ask before continuing.*

1. Go into Settings and turn off all syncs. Go to Settings/Apps/ locate the Google apps you don't want running. Clear data and disable each, one at a time. (Leave Play Store, Play Services, Services Framework, and Accounts Manager intact; I'm not sure about Partner Setup and One Time Init, try those, and if not working properly, re-enable)

OR

2. Assuming you are rooted: you can manually uninstall most of the Google apps if you know which ones to remove (Leave Play Store, Play Services, Services Framework, and Accounts Manager intact; I'm not sure about Partner Setup and One Time Init). I use [/system/app mover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.systemappmover) to switch apps from system to user space, then delete from there.

OR

3. Assuming you are rooted: the easiest way of slimming down on the Google apps would be to flash a minimal GApps to your device, that have the core requirements necessary for your apps from Play Store to function properly. you can add on any of the other features after that as needed.

As I stated at the top, make sure you make a backup/Nandroid so any issues can be easily corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good pointers. I'm not rooted so I won't be able to uninstall them, but clearing the data worked.

Comment: @RobertMunteanu Check this link out for rooting and rom! Works with Primus QS!!   http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2316845

Comment: Disabling unwanted apps is a good pointer indeed, which I didn't think of with my answer. +1 for that! What is not needed doesn't need to be running :)

Comment: @Izzy no GApps (blank store) is a good suggestion

Comment: Have not used it myself, but I've got my first Google-free device running. Up to now, F-Droid + Aptoide substitute for Play just fine :) Part 6 of the blog I've linked in my other comment will report about my "self-test" in a couple of days (hopefully). Second device pending for migration ;)

Comment: As someone asked (but removed that comment): Here's the preliminary report: [Android without Google 6: Self-Experiment](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-6?lang=en)

Comment: @Izzy  awesome testing, amazing how much "energy" Google uses

Comment: I was expecting that – but not at that degree. 4d battery time was what I imagined (due to "low use" from my end). 5 days I didn't dream of – but that's what I've got :)

Answer (score 3):

Great answers are posted already. If your device is rooted, you can look for a custom ROM such as CyanogenMod, AOSP ROM, etc. These ROMs do not have Google apps by default. You have to flash them separately. If available, you can install a custom ROM compatible with your device, then install a Micro GApps package (also known as minimal Google apps). The Micro GApps package basically just includes Play Store and core services without all the extras such as Hangout, Google+, Maps, etc. A good resource for custom ROM is XDA forums.

Comment: I don't think there's a custom ROM for my device (  vonino primus qs ), so I'll go with clearing the app data.

Comment: With a custom ROM you could even go without GApps at all, and use the *BlankStore* from NOGAPPS to access Play (details [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-5)). Its latest version (just published a few days ago) even works for updating paid apps – just buying new ones is not possible from *BlankStore*.